# Database Design: Assigning a File to multiple Users

Tags: php, database, laravel, database-design, phpmyadmin

I am currently creating a Filesharing System for learning reasons in Laravel. Currently it is possible to upload Files and then to Download them later. Now I would like to extend it in a way that one File can be downloaded by multiple (but not all) persons.

Currently I have a User Table and the user id is referenced in a File Table. That way I know which File belongs to which User.

The file Table looks kinda like this:

```
id |  filename | user_id |

1  |  doc.php  |    2    |

2  |  fly.php  |    4    |

3  |  dog.jpg  |    3    |

4  |  cat.gif  |    2    |
```

And so forth... That way I can just check if the user_id is the same as the Authenticated and logged in User.

The problem is I couldnt quite figure out how to make a file accessible to multiple users (10-20).
Do I just create a new Table which will look like this:?

```
user_id | file_id_1 | file_id_2 |

1       |     3     |     6     |
```

And everytime a additional file is assigned to a User a new Column is created?

To me this seems like very bad Data Schematic.

Comment: You need to have a `files_users` table with `file_id` and `user_id` columns. Find all the rows where `file_id` matches a particular file to get a list of who can access it. Find all the rows where `user_id` matches a particular user to get a list of the files they can see. This is called a "many to many" relationship, you'll come across it a lot in Laravel.

Comment: Thank you very much Greg. I will look into it.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K

As @Greg has already commented you are best to use a pivot table to link the files and users to each other.

This will allow you to use hasManyThrough relationship to get all the files that are accessable by a user and all the users that have access to a file

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: BelongsToMany, not hasManyThrough

Comment: @Devon BelongstoMany can be used to make a hasManyThrough relationship. hasManyThrough allows for the relationship direct from users to files and reverse but requires the relationships between all the models already be created